# How to configure CKEditor to not intuit HTML special characters?

Tags: ckeditor

Tough to explain, I'm sure this is something in the CKEditor (v4.13.0) config, but I give up and am asking for help if anyone knows.  Here's the example:

User enters a URL with parameters, here's a fragment of that data that shows the issue:

```
<pre>.html?param=group_id=ALL&current=3000</pre>
```

This saves fine, loading it from the database it's exactly as entered, however, when that string is loaded into CKEditor, either via initialization or setData(), it becomes the following (when viewing editor Source):

```
<pre>.html?param=group_id=ALL&curren;t=3000</pre>
```

And as a result, renders in the visual editor as:

```
.html?param=group_id=ALL¤t=3000
```

This is very much not the same thing.  It seems to be interpreting the partial string "&curren" as a malformed HTML character and automatically intuits it should be closed with a semi-colon.

Any ideas on how to disable this behavior in CKEditor so that it doesn't do that?  We are unfortunately stuck on this older version of CKEditor, upgrades are out of scope/budget, regardless of how sensible they would be.